# Closed form for 2 by 2 matrix exponential

Tags: matrix-decomposition, matrix-exponential

I am trying to find the closed form solution for $e^{A}$, where
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}. \quad \mu_1\mu_2 < 0$$

Is there a way to approach this problem without having to manually calculate powers of $A$?  I think the key lies in having to decompose this matrix, perhaps into SVD, but I am not sure how to go about that.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: The standard approach is to diagonalize the matrix: if $A=UDU^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, then $e^A = Ue^DU^{-1}$ and $e^D$ is trivial to compute.

Comment: How would I diagonalize this particular A?  That's where I am stuck.

Comment: The diagonal matrix has $\lambda\pm\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2}$ on the diagonal. Finding $U$ gets a little bit ugly but should not be hard.

Comment: Ok, thank you both.

Comment: Write $A=\lambda I+M$. As $\lambda I$ and $M$ commute, $exp(A)=exp(\lambda I)exp(M)$.  Besides $exp(M)=I+M+(1/2)M^2+... $ is rather easy to compute because $M^2=\mu_1\mu_2 I \implies M^3=\mu_1\mu_2 M, etc...$

Comment: Wow, never would have thought of that!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&\mu_1\\\mu_2&0\end{bmatrix},$$then $A=\lambda\operatorname{Id}_2+B$ and, since $\lambda\operatorname{Id}_2$ and $B$ commute,$$\exp(A)=\exp(\lambda\operatorname{Id}_2)\exp(B)=\begin{bmatrix}e^\lambda&0\\0&e^\lambda\end{bmatrix}\exp(B).$$On the other hand,\begin{align}B&=\begin{bmatrix}0&\mu_1\\\mu_2&0\end{bmatrix}\\B^2&=\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\mu_2&0\\0&\mu_1\mu_2\end{bmatrix}\\B^3&=\begin{bmatrix}0&\mu_1^{\,2}\mu_2\\\mu_1\mu_2^{\,2}&0\end{bmatrix}\\B^4&=\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1^{\,2}\mu_2^{\,2}&0\\0&\mu_1^{\,2}\mu_2^{\,2}\end{bmatrix}\\B^5&=\begin{bmatrix}0&\mu_1^{\,3}\mu_2^{\,2}\\\mu_1^{\,2}\mu_2^{\,3}&0\end{bmatrix}\end{align}and so on … Therefore, if $\exp(B)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then\begin{align}b_{11}=b_{22}&=1-\frac1{2!}\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}^2+\frac1{4!}\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}^4+\cdots\\&=\cos\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right),\end{align}and a similar computation shows that$$b_{12}=\sqrt{-\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}}\sin\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right)\quad\text{and that}\quad b_{12}=\sqrt{-\frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1}}\sin\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right).$$Therefore$$\exp(A)=\begin{bmatrix}e^\lambda\cos\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right)&e^\lambda\sqrt{-\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}}\sin\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right)\\e^\lambda\sqrt{-\frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1}}\sin\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right)&e^\lambda\cos\left(\sqrt{-\mu_1\mu_2}\right)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: A great approach